# URL not found apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

can somebody assist/point me in the right direction:

have deployed my app on a VPS and can move to various pages of my app , e.g. myIP/django-bookmarks/login or myIP/django-bookmarks/register.....however, when i click on the tabs in the app itself (e.g. register tab), it takes me to myIP/register (without the 'django-bookmarks') and then says "URL not found on this server".

how can i resolve this? note: im new when it comes to deploying and have gotten to this point after a number of errors, tutorial readings and few frustrations this past week.

my Vhost:

```
VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName  django-bookmarks

    DocumentRoot  /var/www/django-bookmarks

    # mod_wsgi settings
#    WSGIDaemonProcess django-bookmarks python-path= /var/www/MyProject/django-$
    WSGIProcessGroup django-bookmarks
    WSGIScriptAlias /django-bookmarks /var/www/django-bookmarks/wsgi.py

    # Static file alias so static files can be referenced by /static/
    Alias /site_media/  /var/www/django-bookmarks/site_media


    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/django-bookmarks/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/django-bookmarks/favicon.ico
    AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /var/www/django-bookmarks/django_bookmarks/site_m$ # Static files permissions
    # Used for serving static files.
    <Directory  /var/www/django-bookmarks/site_media>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Project wsgi permissions
    # Used for serving django pages.
    <Directory  /var/www/django-bookmarks/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Files> </Directory>

    # Project wsgi permissions
    # Used for serving django pages.
    <Directory  /var/www/django-bookmarks/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi.py

```
import os,sys

#comments
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_bookmarks.settings")
sys.path.append('/var/www/django-bookmarks')
sys.path.append('/var/www/django-bookmarks/django_bookmarks')

#comments
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

im pretty sure i made a mistake somewhere, im having a difficult time figuring out where.
any help would be appreciated.
thanks

EDIT:
base.html temp

```
{% block external %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body id="home">
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
        <img src="/site_media/commune.png" height="200" width="400" /><div styl$

    <div class="container">

                <nav>
<a href="/">home</a>
<a href="/popular/">popular</a>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="/save/">submit</a>
<a href="/search/">search</a>
<a href="/tag/">tags</a>
<a href="/user/{{ user.username }}/">{{ user.username }}</a><a href="/logout">logout</a>
{% else %}
<a href="/login/">login</a>
<a href="/register/">register</a>
<a href="/reports/">reports</a>
<a href="/FAQ/">FAQ's</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Don't think its problem with apache/wsgi config. Show us what urls you put when build tabs in templates.

Comment: You've posted the URLconf, but that's not what Rohan asked. You need to post the *templates* where you're outputting the URLs.

Comment: Not your problem, but the first argument to WSGIScriptAlias should have a leading slash. Apache or mod_wsgi is possibly compensating, but still better to fix it.

Comment: Why do you have DocumentRoot directive set to where you do? What is in that directory? You quoted configuration also duplicates Directory block for /var/www/django-bookmarks/.

Comment: Now for your actual problem. Usually this happens because people hard code paths in templates rather than url template tag to construct URL dynamically such that SCRIPT_NAME (which is derived from first argument to WSGIScriptAlias) is automatically added as prefix to the URLs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: i hope i placed the right template. @GrahamDumpleton, i fixed the leading slash; the directory is where i have my project (/var/www/django-bookmarks), the duplicate Directory i only see now, must have copied twice when pasting it here. i;ve been going at it all night, perhaps i need to rest. i will read the link you gave.

Comment: You should not set DocumentRoot to be a directory which is a parent directory of your project. If you do and then muck up certain parts of your Apache configuration, people can download your code, including passwords and secrets in your Django settings file.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton oh really?! woah! wasnt aware of that. thank you. i'll try figure out how to move my project parent directory. concerning the link you gave, im still not clear on the url template tag, would you mind expounding on it or linking to a more 'practical' example i could learn from? i dont have that much experience in Django, im learning as i go

Comment: Also read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton when i try to name the url : "url(r'^popular', archive, name="popular")," and then "<a href={% url "popular" %}>popular</a>" in the template, i get a (500) error. im trying to understand this but im afraid im failing. i will give myself this weekend to further try understand these docs. but in the meantime, please if you do have something you may like to add to shed some light for me,please do. and thanks for your help and patience thus far.

Comment: I don't use Django. Use the Django users mailing list if you want more information about how to use that feature.